# Google Connect JS API, using response_type = code and offline access options

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, google-signin

Initiating the Google Connect, with response_type=code, I am getting in the response the authorization code, but I do not have access for the user who actually approved the app (username, email, etc.)

is there a way to get access to the current user info?

---

Btw, I am actually using this library- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login

and you can find the implementation here- https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/GoogleLogin.js

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with C# app. So I end up automating the google user consent step.

You can try to use a headless browser like PhantonJs to automate the google user consent response and get the access code.

I can try to help more if you can give some more details.